# How to return an anonymous instantiated object in java

Tags: java, object, return, anonymous

At step 4 i have to return an anonymous instantiated Student object using the 4 entered items of information. Since i could not find any forums addressing this, i need some help setting it up or an example.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Students
{
  private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Student[] students;

    students = getStudents();
    printStudents(students);
  }

  private static Student[] getStudents()
  {
    Student[] temp;
    int       how_many;

    System.out.print("How many students? ");
    how_many = input.nextInt();
    purgeInputBuffer();
    temp =  new Student[input.nextInt()];  // Step 1 
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
    {
      getStudent();
      temp[i] = getStudent();     // Step 2
    }
    return temp;    // Step 3
  }

  private static Student getStudent()
  {
    String name,
           address,
           major;
    double gpa;

    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter address: ");
    address = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter major: ");
    major = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter GPA: ");
    gpa = input.nextDouble();
    purgeInputBuffer();

    return ___________________________________________________;     // Step 4
  }

  private static void printStudents(Student[] s)
  {
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)    // Step 5
    {
      System.out.println(______);     // Step 6
    }
  }

  private static void purgeInputBuffer()
  {
    // ----------------------------------------------------
    // Purge input buffer by reading and ignoring remaining
    // characters in input buffer including the newline
    // ----------------------------------------------------
    input.nextLine();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

```
return new Student(constructor args);
```

where `constructor args` are whatever arguments your `Student` constructor requires.

The use of "anonymous" here is not standard Java terminology.  I suppose since you don't assign the object reference to a local variable it could be considered "anonymous".  It won't remain anonymous for long since `getStudent()` is being called in `getStudents()` at

```
temp[i] = getStudent();
```

so the reference will be saved immediately (into the array).

"Anonymous" occurs in the term "anonymous subclass" but that is a completely different concept you probably have not touched on yet.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, didn't think about it in that way

Answer (score 0):

You can make the fields private and use a parametrized constructor to initialize it.

```
public class Students
{
  private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  private String name;
  private String address;
  private String major;
  double gpa;

  public Students(String name, String address, String major, double gpa) {
     this.name = name;
     this.address = address;
     this.gpa = gpa;
     this.major = major;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Student[] students;

    students = getStudents();
    printStudents(students);
  }

  private static Student[] getStudents()
  {
    Student[] temp;
    int       how_many;

    System.out.print("How many students? ");
    how_many = input.nextInt();
    purgeInputBuffer();
    temp =  new Student[input.nextInt()];  // Step 1 
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
    {
      getStudent();
      temp[i] = getStudent();     // Step 2
    }
    return temp;    // Step 3
  }

  private static Student getStudent()
  {
    String name,
           address,
           major;
    double gpa;

    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter address: ");
    address = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter major: ");
    major = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter GPA: ");
    gpa = input.nextDouble();
    purgeInputBuffer();

    return  new Students(name,address,major,gpa);    // Step 4
  }

  private static void printStudents(Student[] s)
  {
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)    // Step 5
    {
      System.out.println(______);     // Step 6
    }
  }

  private static void purgeInputBuffer()
  {
    // ----------------------------------------------------
    // Purge input buffer by reading and ignoring remaining
    // characters in input buffer including the newline
    // ----------------------------------------------------
    input.nextLine();
  }
}
```